# using "going by bus" in Present Participle and Gerund form

Tags: gerunds, present-participles

Compare

> 1. I will look up train ticket prices but I think that **going by bus** is cheaper.

and

> 2. A gloomy man is **going by bus** and thinking his gloomy thoughts to himself.

Is the second sentence unnatural? Is it because the idiom "go by bus/train/plane" is only okay when it's used with **go** as gerund (as in sentence 1) or verb:

> 3. We decided **to go by bus**, and we **went by bus**.

Or is sentence 2 really okay?

Comment: Sentence 2 is fine: the participle is a component of the *progressive* or *continuous* construction. "We decided we're going by bus."

Comment: @StoneyB - thanks! Can we say "I was *going by bus* for many hours and it was driving me crazy"? (I'm trying to come up with an "awkward" sentence). Or is this invalid since I'd need the Past Perfect: "I'd been going by bus"?

Comment: Yes, you can say that; but we would more likely say "I was ***on** the bus* for hours...* It isn't *going* that drives you crazy, it's being stuck there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sentence sounds unnatural to me because there's no destination-phrase or purpose-phrase  mentioned. My ear says the full idiomatic verb-phrase is "going by bus *to* ..."

> A gloomy man is going by bus and thinking his gloomy thoughts to
>   himself.

A gloomy man is *traveling* by bus and thinking ....  OK

A gloomy man is going by bus to meet his long lost cousin.... OK

A gloomy man is going by bus to the Big Apple ... OK

How are you getting into the city?
-- I'm going by bus.                OK too

Hello, honey. I'm out in the boondocks and the cell reception is poor. Can you hear me?
-- Yes, faintly.  What are you doing?
I'm going by bus and thinking of you...     Not OK

P.S. To go by bus (absolute) = to *opt* to travel by bus